# is there difference between running an application from nand and ramdisk?

Tags: filesystems, embedded, virtual-memory, memory-management

I'm using an application on an embedded linux platform. I copied this application to a nand device with a jffs2 filesystem and ran it from there and system performance is significantly degraded.

I think there should be no difference between two scenarios more than startup time because system memory is not full (around 50% used) and the application is not large compared to it. (4MB application, 128MB RAM). so my question is why this performance degradation happens?(what are possible problems)